# Using CF to detect if URL is index.cfm or /

Tags: iis, coldfusion, http-status-code-301

I'm not sure whether this is possible or not using the CGI scope, but what I'm trying to do is detect if a user is browsing a page that is `/index.cfm` or `/`.

In the event of it being `/index.cfm` I would like to do a 301 redirect to the `/`.

I've viewed a dump of the CGI & URL scopes but can't see any easy method of redirecting based on this.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

We are using ColdFusion 10.

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea: why don't you use the rewrite module from Microsoft http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite and do something like

^/index.cfm / [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1):

In CF you can try like this:

```
<cfif listlast(cgi.script_name, "/") eq "index.cfm">
  <cflocation url="redirectlogin.cfm" addtoken="no" statuscode="301">
</cfif>
```

Comment: or you can also use `contains` instead of `EQ` if there are certain conditions too in the URL

Comment: I found in our case we are routing all traffic to index.cfm as the main caller for our entire application, that this field was always populated with index.cfm.  I should have posted that in my original question. but thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Because we are using IIS, we have applied this

```
  <cfset stHttpRequestData = getHttpRequestData()>
  <cfif stHttpRequestData.headers["X-REWRITE-URL"] IS "/index.cfm">
      <cflocation url="http://www.domainname.com/" addtoken="no" statuscode="301">
  </cfif>
```